# What does this matrix algebra mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

If $A$ is a matrix of size $R^{h\times w}$, then what's the meanning of $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$? Does it means $\sqrt{A_{ij}}$ or $-\sqrt{A_{ij}}$?

There is a formula as follows:
$$
f(x)=x^T D x,x\in R^{d\times 1}, D\in R^{d\times d}
$$
then, we could let the following formulas
$$
y=D^{\frac{1}{2}}x
$$
to get the following formula
$$
f(y)=y^Ty.
$$
Is there any difference between the domain of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible when $D$ is positive semi-definite. Since $D$ is related to a quadric, it is implicitly assumed that it is symmetric. A symmetric matrix $D$ can be diagonalized by orthonormal matrices $M$:
$$
D=M\Lambda M^T,\quad \Lambda=\text{diag}(\underbrace{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n}_{\text{eigenvalues}})
$$
In the case $D$ is positive semi-definite, meaning its eigenvalues are all non-negative, $D^{1/2}$ could only mean:
$$
D^{1/2}=M\Lambda^{1/2} M^T,\quad \Lambda^{1/2}=\text{diag}(\lambda_1^{1/2},\dots,\lambda_n^{1/2})
$$
It is easy to check that $D^{1/2}D^{1/2}=D$:
$$
D^{1/2}D^{1/2}=M\Lambda^{1/2} \underbrace{M^TM}_{\text{cancel out}}\Lambda^{1/2} M^T=M\Lambda M^T
$$
If $D^{-1/2}$ is needed, $D$ should be positive definite.

There should be no difference between the domain of $x$ and $y$ if $D$ is positive definite (non-singular). When $D$ is only positive semi-definite, meaning it does not have a full rank, the domain of $y$ is restricted to its image.

Answer (score 1):

$A^{\frac12}$ should be a matrix $X$ with the property that $X^2=A$. As with real numbes, taking the square root is not always possible and requires a a choice otherwise - where the natural choice and convention for $a\ge 0$ is that $\sqrt a$ is the *unique* nonnegative solution of $x^2=a$. Such a choice is less obvious with matrices. If $A=D$ is a diagonal matrix, then a matrix square root can be taken simply entry-wise on the diagonal - provided these are nonnegative; and in that case we use the convention again to pick the nonnegative square roots. Thus $\sqrt D:= (\sqrt{d_{i,j}})$ has the desired property $(\sqrt D)^2=D$ if $D$ is positive semidefinite diagonal. If $A$ is conjugate to a diagonal, $A=BDB^{-1}$, then we notice that $(B\sqrt D B^{-1})^2=A$, so here we can define a square root as well (but is it unique? Notice that $B,D$ are not unique! Check!)